# Add a custom font with @font-face don't work at all

Tags: html, css, font-face

I'm trying to add an external font to a website, the site does not respond at all.  I'm a beginner and just learning, I work on it all day, thank you for your help.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "Alex";
    src: url(fonts/AlexBrush-Regular.ttf) format('truetype'),
         url(fonts/AlexBrush-Regular.woff) format('woff'),
         url(fonts/AlexBrush-Regular.woff2) format('woff2');
}



body {
  text-align: center;
}


h1 {
  color: black;
  font-family: "Alex";
}

.space p {
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: "Alex";
}
```

Comment: My font folder is in the same place as the html and css file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the archive path inside a string
Ex:

```
     url("fonts/AlexBrush-Regular.ttf") format("truetype"),
     url("fonts/AlexBrush-Regular.woff") format("woff"),
     url("fonts/AlexBrush-Regular.woff2") format("woff2");
```